# Is it possible to define an array to hold math operators [+ - * /] in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Is it possible to define an array to hold math operators [+ - * /] in Matlab?

I have an array of numbers [1 1 1 1], i.e. 4 digits. I would like to go over all possible digit combinations, changing the numbers in the array in a loop, and all mathematical operations between them (preferably changed within a loop as well), to see all the possible ways to get the number '24' with basic math operations from four digits.

I thought this might be written in only a few lines code, if it is possible to define such an array of operators in some sort.

Is it ?
Any other way to do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) of [function handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html) like this (see `help plus`, `help minus`, or even 
`help /`, etc.):

```
operators = {@plus,@minus,@times,@rdivide};
```

Then, e.g., `operators{1}(array(1),array(3))` will add the first and third element of your array. There are more pieces to solving your problem. You may want to use [`perms`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html), for example.